# SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with FixedBackOff ignoring interval - spring kafka 2.7.0

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using a simple listener factory with SeekToCurrentErrorhandler with FixedBackOff:

```
    @Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> stringKafkaListenerContainerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {

    ErrorHandlingDeserializer<String> errorHandlingDeserializer = new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new StringDeserializer());
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
            errorHandlingDeserializer, errorHandlingDeserializer);
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(10000L, 10L)));
    factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    return factory;
}
```

This configuration is working only partly: it stops (with finally logging ERROR org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler - Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=10000000, currentAttempts=11, maxAttempts=10} exhausted for ...) after the 10 retries - but the interval of 10000ms is ignored: it retries without any delay.

I don't understand why the interval gets ignored...

ConsumerConfig logs following on startup:

```
2021-05-10 12:19:30,491 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig   - ConsumerConfig values:
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [broker:29092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = some-service-0
    client.rack =
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = commissioning
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_committed
    key.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
```

any idea why this interval gets ignored?

Comment: Not clear what `spring-kafka` version you use, but probably this issue is the same problem as you are facing: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1785

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in 2.7.0; fixed in 2.7.1 due next week https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1786. Or, you can drop back to 2.6.7.

Comment: oh, sorry, version was missing: yes I'm on 2.7.0...
thanks for your fast response!